# how to include EffectiveBasePermissions with Files or Folders REST endpoint for SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need the "current user" permissions on the SharePoint objects when "browsing" the folder tree.  In order to **not** round-trip to the SharePoint server for every file or folder returned in my /Files or /Folders call (listing all files or folders in the relative server url, respectively), I would like to include ("select/expand?") the EffectiveBasePermissions of the current user in the returned results.

I have been unable to accomplish this with explicitly expanding ListItemAllFields, or even ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments.

Does anyone know how to tell the /Files and/or /Folders REST endpoint to include this information with each result?

Thanks in advance,
AJ

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are utilizing the [`FileCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileCollection) or [`FolderCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FolderCollection) resources endpoints.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve files from a root folder of library including information about effective permissions on the associated list item that are assigned to the current user:

```
Endpoint: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/rootFolder/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields/EffectiveBasePermissions
Method: GET
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am using "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/xxx/yyy/zzz')/Files?$select=*&$expand=CheckedOutByUser,LockedByUser,ListItemAllFields/EffectiveBasePermissions"  This returns a lot of info, but it never returns anything named "EffectiveBasePermissions".

Comment: Ah, I changed it to $select=*,ListItemAllFields/EffectiveBasePermissions&$expand=... (so it shows up in both the select and the expand, and it appears to be working now.  Is it legal (and does it work as-expected) to use select=*,more_fields ?  EDIT: No, this causes me to lose all the other ListItemAllFields data. :(

Comment: I have to say that verified it against SharePoint Online and it seems the behavior is a bit different. That's right, the syntax `$select=*,more_fields` is correct

Comment: I tried adding both ListItemAllFields and ListItemAllFields/EffectiveBasePermissions to both select and expand and it didn't work.  Once I add the /EffectiveBasePermissions to them both, I lose all the general ListItemAllFields properties (which I really need).